# How to tell if back/forward buttons triggered argumentsChanged event in Spotify apps?

Tags: javascript, spotify

I am using [application URIs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/#applicationuris) and the `argumentsChanged` event to trigger page renders in my Spotify app. The pages are rendered afresh, scolled to the top of the page. For just browsing around using links and the sidebar and so on, this makes sense.

However, the native back and forward buttons trigger the same events. If a user clicks the back button, I don't want to reset the page and scroll to the top - I want to restore the previous state, like would happen in a normal browser.

How can I differentiate between these two types of navigation?